# Adding whitespace to the end of a cell in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm using Microsoft Excel for Mac 2011, and using `=Cell_Address & rept(" ",x)` is not allowing me to create whitespace at the end of a cell. It is allowing me to add whitespace elsewhere in the cell, just not at the end. Is anyone aware of an alternative or perhaps a setting I can toggle to make Excel acknowledge the whitespace?

Comment: ... It seems to work for me - But I'm on Windows... What specifically does it end up looking like for you??

Comment: When you say not allow, does it result in an error? or just no whitespaces. Does it work if you use say a "."?

Comment: Just no whitespaces. Works great with other characters.

Comment: So, something like this works wonderfully:
="Hello,"&rept(" ",5)&"world."

Comment: If `="Hello,"&rept(" ",5)&"world."` works wonderfully, is it ONLY not working when the `rept(" ",5)` is at the END of the equation?

Comment: Yes, it is at the end.

Comment: If you manually add white space to the end of a cell, is it removed?

Comment: Yes indeed. (And again, only at the end).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an empty cell, adding as many spaces as desired in that cell, and then concatenate the cells with "&".

Answer (score 0):

Comments

- If you manually add white space to the end of a cell, is it removed? – James Jenkins 7 hours ago
- Yes indeed. (And again, only at the end). – Atticus29 2 hours ago

So the solution is - the space is mostly likely added by the forumal, but Mac Excel is removing it.

Revaluate why you need white space and find a different solution/question, to meet the need.